# Http requests parameters with Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I develop a web application using Entity framework.

I have a DbSet inside my DbContext - table for letters.

Is it good practice for a controller method to take a db object as a parameter. Meaning:

```
 [HttpPost]
 Public IHttpActionResult SendLetter(Letter letterToSend)
```

Currently taking a Letter which is a direct Database model. 
Should it be changed to a different model and cast it later on?

Comment: If Letter is the entity being saved to the database then this approach is considered bad practice. Consider using a ViewModel for this which should contain properties that you need for a specific process such as sending a letter, etc. Take note that a ViewModel for SendLetter (in example) is not limited to the properties of the Letter class. You can add other properties as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework with Code First, has at least made it possible to use the Data Object (dbobject) as the POCO Domain Model object as well. We really don't think of it as Data Objects primarily. They are thought of as Domain Models So that is that.

So instead of db-object being used as controller action parameter, the question becomes "can i use the domain model directly in your controller action parameter?"   a db-object to controller parameter would be definitely a no-no on first look. But with a domain model as action parameter:

The opinions will of course vary, and NOTHING PREVENTS you from using the domain model as-is in the action parameter. If the API is dealing with resources, which are 100% represented by the domain models, there is really no harm.

Having said that, a lot of times, real world application tend to grow complicated. Multiple versions of them are created, so v1 supports 10 fields of Letters, whereas v2 could support 12 fields. Also, there are specific validation rules, you might want to run on certain type of inputs. Add to that, the fact that not all requests map to domain models. (patch requests, partial updates, composite models etc.)

and as your API matures, you don't want a small change in one API method, affect several APIs, since all those input models are affected by the changes here.

Hence the safer option is to go with a separate "ResourceModel" design for objects at the controller level. They can be easily mapped to/from Domain models manually or using frameworks like AutoMapper etc. Yes, it is tedious, but helps you in the long run to isolate validation, targeted payloads, v1 v2 specific models etc.

This is purely based on personal experience over a decade of service development, and as i said, opinions vary.